# Ionisation energy and excitation potential

Tags: atomic-physics

I came across the following question:

> If the first ionisation potential of a hypothetical atom is 16 $V$, then what will be the first excitation potential?

I don't understand exactly what they mean by the **first** excitation potential. Could someone explain please? Thanks in advance :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This probably assumes a hydrogen type energy level diagram and the first excitation potential is the energy required by an electron to jump from the ground state level up to the next energy level.

Comment: So from n=1 to n=2?

Comment: If it is a hydrogen type atom then yes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that excitation potential for a given energy level is defined as the potential through which an electron starting from rest must be accelerated to gain the energy required for it to be excited from the ground level to that state. But, for an electron in n=1, what does this even mean?! Are u absolutely sure that this means for n=1 to n=2?

Comment: Similar to how, the "1st excited state" is actually the 2nd energy level in an atom, I think they mean that the ionisation potential, which is defined as the potential through which an electron starting from rest must be accelerated to gain the energy required for it to be moved from the ground state to n=∞ is 16 $V$ and now they want us to calculate the excitation potential of the SECOND excited state. I worked it out and the answer is 12$V$ which matches with the answer key! Thanks! :)